# How to select elements inside two elements using xpath?

Tags: xpath

```
                <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="arrow unavailable"><a href="#">«</a></li>
                <li class="current"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a
                <li><a onclick="3</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="4</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="5</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="6</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="7</a></li>
                <li class="unavailable"><a href="#">…</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="21);return false;" href="#">21</a></li>
```

How would I select all "A" in between current and unavailable?

Comment: Please edit the question and paste the sample HTML that you've linked (as a text). Also, have you made any attempts to solve it?

Comment: Yes many for about 5 hours. It has drove me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

To those that read this in the future, this is what worked for me.

```
/UL[1]/LI[@class=''][span("li[@class='unavailable']")][@class != 'current']/a
```